# DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged doesn't run when original value is reset on the client

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

This seems like a common scenario with an obvious solution, but somehow I haven't encountered it.

I have a `DropDownList` with an event handler bound to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and `AutoPostback="true"`, which works as intended.

The event handler is executed when the value has changed, but if the value is changed via script using jQuery on the client-side, and a post back is subsequently triggered when the user changes the value (and the drop-down's `onchange` event fires), then the server-side code detects that the value hasn't changed since the server last saw its state, and therefore the event handler isn't run on the server side.

It seems like something that would be loaded via view state, but disabling `ViewState` has no effect.

1. The page renders the drop-down with the value "A" selected.
2. The user changes the drop-down list to value "B".
3. The value is automatically posted to the server, and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler is executed.
4. A client script is run to change the value on the client back to "A" using `jQuery.val()`.
5. The user changes the value back to "B".
6. The value is automatically posted to the server, but because the value was "B" when the server last rendered the page, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler is not executed.

### Client-side

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dlst_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnChange" runat="server" Text="Change" OnClientClick="return changeDDL(this,event)" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDDL(sender, e) {
        var dlst = $("#<%= dlst.ClientID %>");
        dlst.val(dlst.val() === "A" ? "B" : "A");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

### Server-side

```cs
protected void dlst_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnChange.Text = dlst.SelectedValue == "A" ? "Change B" : "Change A";
}
```

Comment: Does it help if you reset the SelectedIndex as part of the SelectedIndexChanged event handler? e.g. dlst.SelectedValue = "A";

Comment: @tomtoughton - No, no effect. The problem appears to be in the loading of the subsequent postback, not something I can change when `SelectedIndexChanged` is actually fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging the [.Net Framework Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), I've concluded the problem is deep in the `DropDownList` implementation, and can't be remedied without reimplementing or inheriting the class to change the behavior.

In the `DropDownList` class, there is a `LoadPostData()` implementation of the `IPostBackDataHandler` interface method.

Inside `LoadPostData()`, the index of the value currently selected in the drop-down is compared against the `SelectedIndex` property that is either loaded from `ViewState` or defaulted to `0` when `EnableViewState="false"` is set on the drop-down.

The `OnSelectedIndexChanged()` method is called by the `RaisePostDataChangedEvent()`, which, as the name indicates, is only called if the post data has changed in comparison to the viewstate/default data. Therefore, if the currently selected index matches the viewstate/default index, the `SelectedIndexChanged` event doesn't fire.

In my case, two things can cause the issue:

1. With `ViewState` enabled, the current index value matches the `SelectedIndex` value loaded from `ViewState`, so `SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't fire.
2. With `ViewState` disabled, the `SelectedIndex` value is defaulted to `0`, so when the current index value is `0`, `SelectedIndexChanged` doesn't fire.

**DropDownList.LoadPostData()**

```
protected virtual bool LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) { 
    //{snip...}
    int n = Items.FindByValueInternal(selectedItems[0], false);

    if (SelectedIndex != n) {
        SetPostDataSelection(n); // Calls ListControl.SetPostDataSelection() and sets Items[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
        return true;
    } 

    return false; 
}
```

Later, when the `Page` class is going through the controls whose post data has changed, the drop-down's `OnSelectedIndexChanged` method is called if a change was detected. Since the drop-down's post data hasn't changed in this case, the event isn't raised.

**DropDownList.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()**

```
protected virtual void RaisePostDataChangedEvent() { 
    //{snip...}
    OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty); 
}
```